# Why doesn't CTRL + C exit vim?

Tags: vim, conventions, sigint

I'm aware that if I press <kbd>esc</kbd> followed by typing `:q!`, I can exit the `vim` editor, due to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor).

However, the standard convention is for programs to exit when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> is pressed, which sends a `SIGINT` to the currently running process.

For example, `top`, `tail -f`, and `ping` all follow this convention.

My question is this: *Why* doesn't `vim` follow this well-established convention? Is there a historical reason, or is it something else?

It seems to me that it would avoid a lot of confusion for new users if it followed this standard convention like everything else.

*(While we're at it, why is it `SIGINT` and not `SIGTERM` in the first place?)*

Comment: Vim likely does it because vi does it. Vi likely does it because ex does it. Ex likely does it because ed did it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick And ed does it because doing it is the standard convention for Ctrl+C: to return to the toplevel loop. In interactive programs, the toplevel loop is not the shell. And that's part of why there's SIGINT and SIGTERM: SIGINT goes to the toplevel loop, SIGTERM terminates the program and returns to the shell.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense @Gilles! I didn't find that question that this one has been marked a duplicate of when I searched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is this: Why doesn't vim follow this well-established convention? Is there a historical reason, or is it something else?

Because `vim` is following another old and well-established convention, where Control-C inside an interactive program will abort the current command, not the whole program. This convention is also followed by interactive shells -- a Control-C will not kill your shell, but the command it was running or going to run.

Programs which don't follow that convention usually try to palliate the horror by catching the `SIGINT` and asking the user "do you really want to quit", or "use quit to exit", etc, which turns them from nasty to annoying.

Other very well established conventions for Control-C are to use it as a prefix for other commands (as in emacs-inspired programs, where Control-G takes the role of Control-C) or to copy the selection to the clipboard.

Comment: Ah, I see! That's cleared it up. Thanks :-)